# Cross domain HTTP post request issue after hosting on heroku

Tags: node.js, http, post, heroku

I have hosted a simple nodejs app on heroku with a route for 'post'. I am trying to access its post API from an Angular application - not from same domain. I am getting 405 (Method not allowed) in my browser console.

As far as i have searched, I have learnt HTTP POST and PATCH methods are restricted for cross-domain access. Can someone help me in accessing this POST method?

Answer (score 0):

In order to enable CORS in an express.js app you need to send the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. You can add a middleware somewhere around the start the of the application:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using **cors** middleware like below

```
var express = require('express'),
cors = require('cors'),
app = express();

app.use(cors());

//add HTTP request handlers
```